# Improve performing SQL / JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

TABLE1 listing all test questions before test.

TABLE 1:

```
testid  qnid    qn
1       1       currency of iran
1       2       highest peak        
1       3       longest bridge
```

TABLE 2 listing test responses as status after test for all students :

TABLE 2:

```
studentid   testid  qnid    status  

    1       1       1       unanswered      
    1       1       2       unanswered  
    2       1       1       unanswered  
    2       1       2       answered
```

The TABLE 2 given is incomplete as it does not contain response for all qnid.

The RESULT should be table listing all testid, qnid from TABLE 1 of test with  studentid,status from TABLE 2 for the matching testid,qnid for studentid=2

i.e. RESULT:

```
testid  qnid    studentid    status     
1       1       2           unanswered
1       2       2           answered
1       3
```

TABLE 2 does not contain value for testid=1 qnid=3 from TABLE 1 so
its space should be left empty in RESULT table.

The query I used:

```
select distinct table1.testid,table1.qnid,table2.status 
from table1 
  left outer join table2 
    on table1.testid = table2.testid 
where (table2.studentid = 2 
or table2.studentid =NULL)
```

But instead the output is:

```
testid  qnid    status
1       1       unanswered
1       1       answered
1       2       unanswered
1       2       answered
1       3       unanswered
1       3       answered
```

Comment: There is nothing in your table to JOIN on,use a select with multiple conditions or do a better db design.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the table2.studentid =NULL should do.

```
select distinct table1.testid,table1.qnid,table2.status 
from table1 
  left outer join table2 
    on table1.testid = table2.testid 
where table2.studentid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to join on the question id… So you're join would look like this:

```
table1 left outer join table2 on table1.testid = table2.testid AND table1.qnid = table2.qnid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct table1.testid,table1.qnid,coalesce(table2.student_id,NULL),table2.status 
from table1 
  left outer join table2 
    on table1.testid = table2.testid 
where table2.studentid = 2
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?